# Would a difficult to access "Key" be an option to securely solve the Apple vs. FBI problem?

Tags: legal, end-to-end-encryption

In recent times, there has been an escalating demand by legislators in the US and the world around to be able to decrypt phones that come pre-configured with strong encryption.  Key escrow is commonly suggested as a solution, with the risk seeming to arise out of the escrow agent misusing or not appropriately securing the keys — allowing for remote, illegal, or surreptitious access to the secured data.

Could a system secure from remote attack be devised by adding an offline tamper-evident key to the device?  This could be an unconnected WLCSP flash chip or a barcode within the device with the plaintext of a decryption key.

[image: WLCSP flash memory device]

I recognize the evil maid attack, but presume a tamper seal could be made sufficiently challenging to thwart all but the most motivated attackers from surreptitious access to the data.

What would be lost in this scheme relative to the current security afforded by a consumer-grade pre-encrypted device (cf. iPhone)? Bitcoin, Subpoena efficacy, and other scenarios that seem fine with "smash and grab" tactics come to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Your proposal seems to be a device-specific key which is somehow placed on the device with the intention that only "authorized" law agencies can read. Only, this does not actually solve the problem since it is not that much a technical problem in the first place. It is easy to create a backdoor nobody can access. The problem starts then to make sure that only the right people can access it (whoever these are) and only for the right purpose (whatever this means).

It is not an FBI problem but a world-wide issue - most governments want to have access to the encrypted data in case of severe crimes although definition of what is considered a severe crime differ. Thus who should get access to this backdoor then: the secret services of every country where a phone gets sold? Or do you want country specific backdoors And how a customer can be sure which country has access to the specific backdoor on your phone? And how can be guaranteed that the knowledge on how to access the (country specific?) backdoor keys stays only with the agency which is supposed to have the keys while still being flexibel enough to be usable in multiple places where the agency has offices?

The main problem is not how to securely implement a backdoor so that the average criminal has no access to it. The problem is more how to make sure that **only** the legally allowed agencies get access to the key and will **only** use it for legally allowed purposes.

Comment: I to a certain extent do not understand the questions posed in your answer.  The key premise of the proposal is tying the _ability_ to utilize a backdoor to that of possession of the device.  The key is a literal physical key not stored anywhere but within the device - unique per device, so only someone with possession of device would permit them to access it forcibly. 
My question was "assuming a backdoor which presupposes possession combined with tamper evidence, what security benefit would be lost?"

Comment: @Mitch: *.... so only someone with possession of device would permit them to access it forcibly."* - So you mean that everybody which gets in possession of a device should be able to use this backdoor? This would probably be terrible idea since it essentially bypasses all protections which were specifically introduced so that no just getting access to a device (short access, stolen ...) opens full access to the device. If this is not your goal then please explain how you want to make sure that only authorized persons can use this backdoor and only for the legally allowed reasons?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed how iPhones (and Samsung, I wouldn't know about Huawai or others) work already, and have worked for a long, long time.

And that is exactly the problem, it's not what governmental agencies want, which is why they're so desperately trying to get something different implemented.

The decryption key is stored in a chip that does encryption/decryption in hardware, and which, although technically "connected", has no connection whatsoever that would permit reading out the key. The only way of getting at the data stored on the phone is by handing the data to the chip and convincing the chip to be nice and do the decryption. For which, well, you need a kind of authentication token (PIN, biometric data, whatever).

What government agencies want is to be able to decrypt your stuff **whithout** that token, as often and any time they like, remotely, and without you noticing. Especially the latter is important beacause you are not to be warned when your data has been compromised (otherwise you might flee, or something).

The idea that your data is to be accessed only in presence of a warrant when there is reasonable evidence that you are a criminal or that there is present and immediate danger is wrong. The idea that there exists a presumption of innocence is wrong. You are a criminal unless proven different.